# API IndexedDB problemas para eliminar objetos

Tags: javascript, html5, indexeddb

soy nuevo en todo esto de la programación y estoy trabajando con la API IndexedDB he estado mucho tiempo analizando mi código y no encuentro el error de ante mano gracias por la ayuda. El problema es el siguiente el botón de eliminar cada uno de los objetos (que aquí se llaman así pero son más o menos un registro) no funciona he hecho algunas pruebas y nada la función eliminar parece trabajar bien pero los datos no se borran aquí les dejo el código

```
   var bd;
function iniciar(){

    zonadatos=document.getElementById("zonadatos");

    boton=document.getElementById("grabar");


    boton.addEventListener("click",agragarobjeto, false);

    var solicitud=indexedDB.open("mibase6");

    solicitud.onsuccess=function(e){

        bd=e.target.result;

    eliminartodo(); 

    }

    solicitud.onupgradeneeded=function(e){

                bd=e.target.result;
        bd.createObjectStore("gente", {keyPath: "iden", autoIncrement:true});

    }   


}

function agragarobjeto(){

    var clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;

    var titulo=document.getElementById("texto").value;

    var Fecha=document.getElementById("fecha").value;

    var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");

    var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");

    var agregar=almacen.add({clave: clave, titulo: titulo, Fecha: Fecha});

    agregar.addEventListener("success", mostrar, false);


    document.getElementById("clave").value=""

    document.getElementById("texto").value=""

    document.getElementById("fecha").value=""
}

function mostrar(){

    zonadatos.innerHTML="";

    var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"],"readonly");

    var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");

    var cursor=almacen.openCursor();

    cursor.addEventListener("success", mostrarDatos, false);    


}

function mostrarDatos(e){

    var cursor=e.target.result;

    if(cursor){

        zonadatos.innerHTML+='<p> <input type="number" style="width:60px" name="codigo" required="" id="codigo"  value="' + cursor.value.clave + '" disabled> <input type="number" name="cfija" style="width:60px" required="" id="cfija" value="' + cursor.value.titulo + '" disabled> <input type="number" name="cfija" style="width:60px" required="" id="cvariable" value="' + cursor.value.Fecha + '" disabled> <button style="width:60px" type="button" onclick="eliminar(\'' +cursor.value.iden+ '\')">Eliminar</button>  </p>' ;

        cursor.continue();

        hola.innerHTML+="hola";
    }



}

function eliminar(valor){
    var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");
    var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");
    var solicitud=almacen.delete(valor);
    solicitud.addEventListener('success', mostrar, false);
    solicitud.addEventListener('error', errores, false);
    hola.innerHTML+=valor;
}

function eliminartodo(){
    var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");
    var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");
    var solicitud=almacen.clear();

}

function errores(){
alert("Error:");
}


window.addEventListener("load", iniciar, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo presentado [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/delete), se detalla que el valor de retorno del método `delete()` es un objeto [IDBRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest) y que si la solicitud se ha completado con éxito, el resultado estará disponible a través de la propiedad `result` y a su vez se  disparará un evento que indica el éxito en la solicitud [IDBRequest.onsuccess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest/onsuccess). De esta forma, para determinar si tu solicitud tuvo éxito, sería de esta forma, por ejemplo:

```
function eliminar(valor){
    var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");
    var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");
    var solicitud=almacen.delete(valor);
     solicitud.onsuccess = function(event) {
     //Reportar el éxito de la solicitud delete
     };
    }
```

Comment: Colega continua igual gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hola @Deadpool909105 Hice una lectura superficial del código y me parece que `var db;` no es inicializada dentro del mismo. Pienso que ese podría ser el problema a resolver.